# implement voting system using node.js, mongodb and ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm pretty new to node.JS and ejs. I have searched `how to implement real-time voting system like Stackoverflow voting` using the mentioned technology. But I don't have any Idea how to do it.

here is my front-end code:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < gamePasses.length; i++) {%>
    <form dir="ltr">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= i + 1 %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= gamePasses[i].teamName %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= gamePasses[i].password %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= gamePasses[i].votes %>
            </td>
            <td onclick="vote('<%= gamePasses[i].password %>')">
                <i class="material-icons">
                    thumb_up
                </i>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </form>
<% } %>

<script>
    function vote(pass) {
        $.post('/user/vote/' + pass)
    }
    function passSubmit() {
        $.post('/user/gamePassword', {
            gamePassword: $('#password').val()
        }).done(() => {
            window.location.assign('/user/scoreboard')
        })
    }
</script>
```

back-end code:

```
uter.post('/vote/:gamePassword', (req, res) => {
    gamePassword = req.params.gamePassword;
    gamePassModel.find({password: gamePassword}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else {
            result.votes += 1
            result.save((err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err)
            })
        }
    })
})
```

This code problems are:

1. Doesn't support real-time voting
2. each user can votes many times

I will be thankful if anyone could help me

Comment: you looks not so new to StackOverflow, you should know this kind of questions are not well-received. Basically you didn't try anything and you're asking us to do your work for you.
That said: In node.js you have to write at least some resources to *get* and *update* votes related to each post. Front-end side you have to call and use those routes.

Comment: @alfredopacino I really didn't want to do so. I edit my post. please guide me how to implement it real-time using ejs and nodejs

Comment: you can take a look here for example of real-time server https://pusher.com/tutorials/live-poll-nodejs/ . Or you can take a look at socket.io https://socket.io/ . Anyway this wouldn't be the first exercise I would assign to a nodejs newbie..

Comment: @alfredopacino the `pusher` uses angular in the front side but I don't want to use it

Comment: I linked it as real-time server example. But the frontend code is so much simple you can easily extract the logic from angular

Comment: @alfredopacino is there any way to implement it not real-time but it solves the `each user can votes many times` problem?

Comment: you can approach the problem in few different ways: 1. checking for the voter IP; 2. using cookies; 3. if your site have a login guard, you can associate the vote to an username and prohibit multiple votes from the same user

Comment: @alfredopacino you mean that I should save each voter id in database and then check whether he/she votes before to the post I want to take votes for that?

Comment: well, you can save each vote along with the voter. So each vote is associate to a voter

Comment: @alfredopacino would you plesae give me some pseudocode as answer?

Answer (score 1):

For prohibit multiple vote from the same user, you can think something like this. Didn't test it but the logic should works.

```
uter.post('/vote/:gamePassword', (req, res) => {
gamePassword = req.params.gamePassword;

//you can retrieve the voter id the way you want (in this case I assumed the query string contains it)
let voterId = req.query.voterId

gamePassModel.find({password: gamePassword}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else {

        //votes in not a number anymore. Now it's an array of IDs, you have to change the model (in Mongoose, I suppose)

        if(~result.votes.indexOf(voterId)) {
           result.votes.push(voterId)  

            //I'm pretty sure you cannot call save() like you do on this object, but this is not part of the question here, check the mongoose docs
            result.save((err) => {
            if (err) res.json({error:err});
           })          
        } else res.json({ error: "you already voted" });


    }
})
})
```

Now when you want to get the total vote of something, you have to make a count query (still assuming mongodb/mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count)